# How to handle multiple database connections using session factories with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring

I'm really new to Hibernate and have been mulling over something for a while now. I have two databases that I have JNDI connection strings defined to in Tomcat's context.xml. In my application which uses Spring and Hibernate I have 2 session factories the first one is as follows -->

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>
    <prop key="current_session_context_class">true</prop>

    <!--HSQL-->
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/xxx</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>

  </props>
</property>
<property name="annotatedClasses">
  <list>
    <value>com.mytest.examples.Person</value>
    <value>com.mytest.examples.Customer</value>
    <value>com.mytest.examples.Employee</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

The second sessionFactory points to the second database as follows

```
<bean id="sessionFactory2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>
    <prop key="current_session_context_class">true</prop>

    <!--HSQL-->
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/yzz</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>

  </props>
</property>
<property name="annotatedClasses">
  <list>
    <value>com.mytest.examples.Container</value>
    <value>com.mytest.examples.Credentials</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

Now when I try and make use of these factories using the following

```
Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

I always get the first factory by default and am able to access all the tables in its schema but not the second one. How do I specify which factory I want to use?

Answer (score 1):

The `HibernateTemplate` constructor takes a `SessionFactory` as argument. I don't know what `getHibernateTemplate()` does in your code, but it should return a `HibernateTemplate` built with one of the SessionFactory beans you defined (either by declaring them in the spring context xml file, or by constructing them in Java from one of the injected session factories).

Note that, as the documentation of HibernateTemplate says (in bold):

> As of Hibernate 3.0.1, transactional
>   Hibernate access code can also be
>   coded in plain Hibernate style. Hence,
>   for newly started projects, consider
>   adopting the standard Hibernate3 style
>   of coding data access objects instead,
>   based on
>   SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().

I would inject the session factory directly, and use the Hibernate API directly. HibernateTemplate doesn't bring much over the Hibernate API and often gets in the way, IMHO. (For example by not providing an equivalent to `Query.uniqueResult()`).

Comment: Hi JB, thanks for replying. I am using Spring's 'getHibernateTemplate()' method that I call a getSessionFactory() on. However neither of them accept an argument where I can specify the ID of the sessionFactory I want to use that I have defined in the hibernate.cfg that I have included in my original post above. 

I tried using the HibernateTemplate directly, but I still don't find a way to specify which sessionFactory I want the template to return. 

Wouldn't SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() return the default session in that file?

Comment: On which object/type do you call getHibernateTemplate()? As for getCurrentSession(): it's an instance method. You can inject the two session factories you have defined in your object, and call getSessionFactory on one or the other, depending on the database you want to target.