# Is there any way to rebuild a sessionFactory?

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

We are building an application where we connect to multiple database schemas.
The first schema contains the schema name and other details of the second schema.
The application runs fine for the first time. But it pops an error when I login again.
The error is :

```
 org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
```

I have two sessionFactories,one for each database.
But the properties change according to who logs in.

I understand it's because the sessionfactory is not getting built again.Is there any way to rebuild the sessionFactory?
Any help here..
Thanks in advance..

EDIT

So we figured we need to use multi tenancy in Hibernate.
Any help on how we could do that?
Any kind of examples links.. etc are greatly appreciated..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [two Session Factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629182/how-to-handle-multiple-database-connections-using-session-factories-with-spring). Once created Session Factories are [immutable](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html).

Comment: I already have two session factories.. But the connection parameter changes for the second session factory depending upon who is logging.. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Create a third one from a Configuration object containing the information obtained from the second one.

Comment: There may be multiple clients who may log in to the system any day.I will have to create that many session factories then.. That is the problem..

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider the design of your app, and use the same Session Factory for many clients.

Comment: Can you provide some links or examples?Thanks.

Comment: Most examples (and real apps) use a single Session Factory, and schema for all users.